# Cann't delete row in php using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql

I am deleting row in PHP using AJAX, but it shows Row can't delete.
My Delete button is like this...

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) 
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["create_date"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["bni_member_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["bni_member_name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["bni_chapter_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["bni_category_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="delete" onclick="delFun()" value="delete" id="<?php echo $row["bni_member_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs delete_data"/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I call a function on the click button. Function like this.
It always Executes part can't delete. I think there is a problem with

```
data: {del_id: del_id},
```

I think there is a problem with Data... but I can't resolve it.

```
   var delfin;
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    delFun = function () {
        $('.delete_data').click(function () {
            var del_id = $(this).attr("name");
            var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.ajax({
                url: "phpfile/delete.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {del_id: del_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data=="YES"){
                        $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                     }else{
                            alert("can't delete the row")
                     }
                }
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

And My PHP file is in another directory like this

```
<?php
    include('../../connection.php');
    $music_number = $_POST['del_id'];
    //echo $music_number;
    $qry = "DELETE FROM bni_member WHERE bni_member_id ='$music_number'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    if(isset($result)) {
       echo "YES";
    } else {
       echo "NO";
    }
?>
```

My table is like

```
CREATE TABLE `bni_member` (
 `bni_member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bni_member_name` text,
 `bni_member_mobile` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_member_email` text,
 `bni_member_website` text,
 `bni_member_bio` text,
 `bni_member_export_to` text,
 `bni_member_import_from` text,
 `bni_member_want_to_connect_to` text,
 `bni_member_company` text,
 `bni_chapter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_member_address` text,
 `bni_member_commitee` text,
 `bni_member_profilepic` longblob NOT NULL,
 `bni_member_logo` longblob NOT NULL,
 `create_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `is_delete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_update` text,
 `del_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bni_member_id`),
 KEY `bni_chapter_id` (`bni_chapter_id`),
 KEY `bni_category_id` (`bni_category_id`),
 KEY `bni_member_id` (`bni_member_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `bni_member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bni_chapter_id`) REFERENCES 
`bni_chapter` (`bni_chapter_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `bni_member_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`bni_category_id`) 
REFERENCES `bni_category` (`bni_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=225 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: don't use `mysql_query` it is deprecated now.

Comment: any error are you getting?

Comment: your API usage is confusing, on the tables, you use `mysqli_fetch_array`, then on the PHP ajax processing, you use `mysql_query`, just use `mysqli`

Comment: I updated this but still I gives row can't delete          
 `$result=mysqli_query($qry);
    if(isset($result)) {
       echo "YES";
    } else {
       echo "NO"; 
    }`   @Ghost

Comment: No I am not getting any error @PathikVejani   I updated `$result=mysqli_query($qry); if(isset($result)) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; }`

Comment: check `var del_id = $(this).attr("name")` should be `var del_id = $(this).attr("id")`

Comment: I updated with `mysqli`  `$result=mysqli_query($qry); if(isset($result)) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; }`    @prakashtank

Comment: I have changed to `var del_id = $(this).attr("id")` @Roy

Comment: @MeetPatel and what happened? You are getting .attr wrong.

Comment: It's because in your js `var del_id = $(this).attr("name");` return "delete" and it do not help for the query. You should add a data attribute on your button, like `data-id="<?php echo $row["bni_member_id"]; ?>` and then get it in JS via `var del_id = $(this).data('id');`. Also you should secure your SQL queries, and use PDO if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that, you're getting `name` attribute from your delete button. You can pass `bni_member_id` as a data attribute instead of using element `id` attribute. It can cause confusion.

And the second problem is that, you're using both `onlick` attribute and jQuery's `click` method. Using one them is pretty enough. Your input button will look like this:

```
<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="delete" class="btn btn-info btn-xs delete_data" data-bni-member-id="<?= $row["bni_member_id"]; ?>" /></td>
```

Then your js will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.delete_data').click(function () {
        var del_id = $(this).data("bni_member_id");
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: "phpfile/delete.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {del_id: del_id},
            success: function (data) {
                if(data=="YES"){
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                } else {
                    alert("can't delete the row")
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can change delete button

```
 <input type="button" name="delete" onclick="delFun()" value="delete" data-id="<?php echo $row["bni_member_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs delete_data"/>
```

And Jquery Event

```
    $(document).on("click",".delete_data",function () {

    var del_id = $(this).data("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my code with you try like this

```
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["exam_name"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["exam_date"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["exam_status"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["exam_comment"]; ?></td>
         <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" id="<?php echo $row["examid"]; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td> 
      </tr>
```

Add script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
           // var id=$(this).data("id3");
            var el = this;
        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split("_");

        // Delete id
        var deleteid = splitid[1];  
           if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"path.....",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{id:id},  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data){  
                           $(el).closest('tr').css('background','#d31027');
                $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){      
                    $(this).remove();
                });  

                     }  
                });  
           }  
      }); 
 </script>
```